# Выполнение рекурсивной и ассинхронной функции в цикле

Tags: javascript

У меня такая дилема: в цикле происходит выполнение рекурсивной и одновременно ассинхронной функции. Как мне отследить, что все рекурсии выполнились и можно продолжить выполнение оставшегося кода?
Вот метод вызова рекурсивной функции

```
colapseHardBranch() {
  this.expandedNode = []
  this.oldRange = 0
  const objTree = this.$refs.tree.store.root.childNodes
  for (var i = 0; i < objTree.length; i++) {
    this._recursiveCollapse(objTree[i])
  }
}
```

а вот сама рекурсивная функция

```
`_recursiveCollapse(node) {
  if (node.expanded) {
    node.collapse()
    if (node.childNodes) {
      for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (node.childNodes[i].expanded) {
          return new Promise(resolve => {
            requestAnimationFrame(() => this._recursiveCollapse(node.childNodes[i]))
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

Comment: "оставшегося кода" - ??

Comment: Ну продолжить выполнение других методов только после выполнения всех этих рекурсий

Comment: `_recursiveCollapse выполнеется внутри самой себя при определенном условии

Comment: Зачем у Ваша функция возвращает `Promise`, если эта `Promise` никому не нужна?

Comment: @Igor, этот promise еще и постоянно `pending`

Comment: По идее requestAnimationFrame вызывает ассинхроннсть, для этого и промис, могу ошибаться, но без него не работает

Comment: Не подскажите как исправить тогда этот код?